# Looking for good advices concerning the use of NFS under Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, nfs

I'm looking for advice regarding the use of NFS under windows 2008.

- Ease of use
- Performance
- Recommendations
  etc...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: how do you want to use NFS under windows? client or server? any specific performance requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft implemnts NFS as SFU (services for unix) -  it is a user mode subsystem. Most recent version is 3.5 also called SUA (subsystem for Unix Applications) starting Windows 2003 R2. 
this has: Microsoft Services for Network File System (NFS) & Identity Management for UNIX.

long term support from MS: SFU general support will continue until 2011; extended support until 2014.

Only Windows server editions of 2003, 2008 can acts as NFS server.
Client editions: Windows-7, Vista support only NFS client (NFS v3)

**ease of use:** my opinion NFS setup on Windows is harder than on Fedora 14.
** performance:** dont know Windows perf but any day Linux NFS server is better

general comment: NFS is active and well supported on Linux. Any manjor distro like Centos/Redhat, Ubuntu, Fedora support NFS client/server.